# Google Retargeting and Conversion Tracking Code Implementation

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics

I'm running into an issue where my conversion tracking code isn't working.

Each piece of code that Google gives you to implement makes reference to the following code:

With retargeting code, you declare several variables:

```
var google_conversion_id = 1111111111;
var google_conversion_label = "WWWWWWWWWWWWWW";
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
```

Then you load the conversion script:

```
http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js
```

... and then for tracking conversions, you also declare some variable and load the same exact script.

We are no experiencing inconsistencies with our data, and I'm suspicious of how all of this code is being loaded within the document. The `conversion.js` script is being loaded several times on the page, when I feel that it should only be loaded once.

Then these variables that are being declared ... some are the same, and obviously overwrite the previously declared variables.

What is the proper way to implement `analytics`, `remarketing` and `conversion` code? Is it just a matter of load priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you should only have one tag firing on any one page, so for example a homepage remarketing tag would fire on all homepage pages, a conversion tag will only fire on the sales confirmation page. Although the script is called conversion.js, it's the same for non conversion pages.

So you should not really see multiple conversion.js calls and if you only have one call, you shouldn't end up overwriting anything.

Alternatively, if you have a tag that fires everywhere, but want to overwrite with a more specific remarketing tag (home page for example) then just make sure its fired second so you overwrite it with the priority one.